# My dropdown button in bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: html, angular, dropdown, bootstrap-5

I've tried all youtube videos, followed all the documentation of bootstrap. Please help me. I can't understand why it's not even working :(

Here's the basic HTML bootstrap code.

```
!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scan-landing.component.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@500&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0- 
 alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0- 
 alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
```

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" 
aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="main">

  <div class="scanner-shell" [hidden]="!hasDevices">

    <select #selectedValue (change)="onDeviceSelectChange()">
      <option [value]=" " [selected]="!currentDevice">No Device Selected</option>
      <option *ngFor="let device of availableDevices" [value]="device.deviceId"
        [selected]="currentDevice && device.deviceId === currentDevice.deviceId">{{device.label}}</option>
    </select>

    <zxing-scanner class="scanner-window" [(device)]="currentDevice" (scanSuccess)="onCodeResult($event)"
      [formats]="formatsEnabled" (permissionResponse)="onHasPermission($event)"
      (camerasFound)="onCamerasFound($event)"></zxing-scanner>


    <!-- <section class="results" *ngIf="qrResultString">
        <div>
          <small>Result</small>
          <strong>{{ qrResultString }}</strong>
        </div>
        <button (click)="clearResult()">&times;</button>
      </section> -->

  </div>

</div>
```

-->

It's so hard to troubleshoot since nothing shows in my console whenever I press it.

Comment: Are you using any front-end frameworks - React, Angular? If yes include them in your tags list

Comment: I'm using Angular. Sorry, wasn't able to understand the question. Do you mean the href in the tags?

Comment: I mean stackoverflow tags

Answer (score 0):

Your included bootstrap files were broken !

You should not split `<link>` or `<script>` into two lines.

```html
<HTML>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scan-landing.component.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@500&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" 
aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="main">

  <div class="scanner-shell" [hidden]="!hasDevices">

    <select #selectedValue (change)="onDeviceSelectChange()">
      <option [value]=" " [selected]="!currentDevice">No Device Selected</option>
      <option *ngFor="let device of availableDevices" [value]="device.deviceId"
        [selected]="currentDevice && device.deviceId === currentDevice.deviceId">{{device.label}}</option>
    </select>

    <zxing-scanner class="scanner-window" [(device)]="currentDevice" (scanSuccess)="onCodeResult($event)"
      [formats]="formatsEnabled" (permissionResponse)="onHasPermission($event)"
      (camerasFound)="onCamerasFound($event)"></zxing-scanner>


    <!-- <section class="results" *ngIf="qrResultString">
        <div>
          <small>Result</small>
          <strong>{{ qrResultString }}</strong>
        </div>
        <button (click)="clearResult()">&times;</button>
      </section> -->

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried to fix it, it still has the same issue :(